# Different results for the same not-void function with missing return in different environment

Tags: c++11, cross-compiling, shared-ptr

I wrote by mistake a **not-void function** that does not return anything. I didn't get warning or some error. I have copied the same function in a *different environment* (this environment has an old version of Ubuntu and the compiler belongs to an older ARM Poky family-GNU GCC 5.x ARM poky, before was FAMILLY GNU GCC 6.x ARM OE) and *I got sgm fault*.

I know that a not-void function has an **undetermined behavior**, but how I can prove that the *compilers* influences this?

Here is a simplification of my function:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> get_ptr()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = nullptr; //missing return
}

int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a = get_ptr();  //what is actually initialize with? 
    if (nullptr == a)
    {
        std::cout << "Is working \n"<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << *get_ptr();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Know somebody explain me what is happening behind the scenes? Will help me a lot any information.

Comment: You're using C++ inside the Linux kernel? If not, why did you include the `linux-kernel` tag?

Comment: I get a warning "control reaches end of non-void function" from LLVM.

Comment: Hey @Barmar, no. I'm using C++11 inside a Vm with Ubuntu installed. I will delete the tag. Thanks! :D I'm really a beginner.

Comment: What's your real question? As you say, it's undefined behavior, so anything can happen. A segmentation fault is possible, so is continuing without any error. It depends on the calling conventions and memory layout of the particular architecture.

Comment: If you want to see what's happening under the covers, look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: I don't know how to loot at generated assembly code, because to compile the code I use bitbake.

Comment: You can use `objdump` to disassemble binaries. On my clang-11 without optimization,  it dies with "Illegal instruction: 4" because LLVM apparently explicitly inserts a reserved undefined `ud2` instruction at the end of the function (presumably to fail fast and aid debugging).

Comment: Hello, @thatotherguy. Thanks for information.  When you said what you got in your clang-11 *without optimization* I start to see if I had different optimizations. And yes in one environment I had optimizations like: " -fomit-frame-pointer ,  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE etc." I google it and certainly  this influence the behavior to a function([https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/21/compiler-and-linker-flags-gcc/]. And as Barmar  said it is influenced by arhitecture too(is different in my two environments.  I think this problem is solved. Thanks guys.